# PostgreSQL granted all privileges on schema, but user still cannot insert a record

Tags: postgresql, permissions, schema

This is maddening.

I'm running PostgreSQL 14 in a Docker container using a [standard image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres).

```yml
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.7"

services:
  pg:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=localdev
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./pg/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

I bootstrap a couple of schemas (`foo` and `bar`) and a couple of users (`foo_dba` and `bar_dba`); and make each user the owner of their respective schema.

```sql
CREATE USER foo_dba WITH PASSWORD 'localdev';
CREATE SCHEMA foo AUTHORIZATION foo_dba;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE postgres TO foo_dba;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA foo TO foo_dba;

CREATE USER bar_dba WITH PASSWORD 'localdev';
CREATE SCHEMA bar AUTHORIZATION bar_dba;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE postgres TO bar_dba;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA bar TO bar_dba;
```

While logged in as `foo_dba`, I create a table called `foo.things` (in the `foo` schema) and grant `bar_dba` the ability to insert records into it.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo.things (
    id            SERIAL        PRIMARY KEY
,   uid           UUID          NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT gen_random_uuid()
,   name          TEXT          NOT NULL
,   created_at    TIMESTAMPTZ   NOT NULL DEFAULT timezone('utc', now())
,   updated_at    TIMESTAMPTZ
);

GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA foo TO bar_dba;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA foo TO bar_dba;
GRANT INSERT ON TABLE foo.things TO bar_dba;
GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE foo.things_id_seq TO bar_dba;
```

I verify the privileges in the appropriate `information_schema` views (e.g. `role_table_grants`, `role_usage_grants`). Just for sanity, I execute the following query as `foo_dba`:

```sql
INSERT INTO foo.things (name)
VALUES ('foo was here!')
RETURNING *;
```

...and it succeeds. So far so good.

Next, I connect to the database as `bar_dba` and attempt to run a similar query:

```sql
INSERT INTO foo.things (name)
VALUES ('bar was here!')
RETURNING *;
```

...and I get access denied.

---

**What I've tried:**

- RTFM to understand [GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) and [Privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html)
- Eliminating everything I can to keep this as simple as possible
- GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA
- GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA
- GRANT INSERT ON TABLE
- GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE for the SERIAL `id` column
- GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA (!!)
- Confirming that `bar_dba` can run SELECT gen_random_uuid()
- Shutting it off and turning it back on again
- docker-compose logs pg
- docker image prune --all -f
- docker volume prune -f

---

**What I expect will happen:**

The owner of `foo` schema should be able to grant permission to another user, to perform an INSERT on a table in the schema they own.

---

**What is actually happening:**

```sql
postgres.public> INSERT INTO foo.things (name)
                 VALUES ('bar was here!')
                 RETURNING *
[2022-01-08 02:02:43] [42501] ERROR: permission denied for table things
```

---

I'm just not seeing it. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant select also.  I believe this is so that the uniqueness of uid and id can be verified.  A grant insert without select could be misused by trying to insert a value, if it fails the user would know that that value already existed.

Correction, the above is valid for the update.

In your case, the returning is the culprit.  Drop that and bar_dba can insert.

Comment: :facepalm: Oof. I knew it would be something so seemingly obvious. Thanks for catching that.